# How to use my cross-compiler to compile something?

Tags: compiling, cross-compilation

I informed about cross-compiling and found many information on how to create one, but very little information on how to use it.

I would like to compile the tool `bluez-utils-3.36` from [this site](http://www.bluez.org/download/) with my own compiler. I found the cross compiler (arm-linux-gcc-4.4.3.tgz) on [this site](https://www.mediafire.com/folder/9cs8fenf225et//2440Board#8wdvqqe9hfjxz). My gcc version is 4.4.3, so i assume that this is the right one.

**Host machine (machine where i build the code)**

```
Processor: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2420 0 @ 1.90GHz
OS Version: Linux 2.6.32-44 generic
```

**Target machine: (the target on which the compiled file should run)**

```
Processor: ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
OS Version: Linux 2.6.35.3-571
```

How can i use this new compiler to compile `bluez-utils-3.36`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a GNU standard naming scheme for compilers and other parts of the toolchain:

```
<target triplet>-<tool name>
```

The [target triplet](http://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet) is of the form

```
<machine>-<vendor>-<operatingsystem>
```

And the tool name is `gcc` for the compiler, or another tool name like `ld` or `strip` or `ar`, etc...

The default compiler, the one that compiles native binaries (is not a cross compiler) is just called as `gcc` without the triplet.

The triplet of the compiler that is inside the file you mentioned in your question is `arm-none-linux-gnueabi` (looks like a quadruplet, I know, but that's what it is). So to use it, just call `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc` instead of plain `gcc`.

If you are building something which uses a `Makefile`, you can often get that `Makefile` to use the compiler you want by running `CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc make` instead of plain `make`. If you are building something which uses a GNU `configure` script, [you can specify the target triplet for that too](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.69/html_node/Specifying-Target-Triplets.html).

Comment: Does not work. I tried to compile a simple hello world program. With `gcc main.c -o main` it works fine. But if i try `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc main.c -o main` then i get the error message `arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc: command not found.`

Comment: Solved: You have to add the path to your cross compiler to the `PATH` variable e.g. `export PATH=~/opt/FriendlyARM/toolschain/4.4.3/bin:$PATH`

Comment: The building of a Makefile did also worked with `CC=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-gcc make`, but it is not creating the necessary files anymore :(

Comment: I noticed this error in the build log:
`/usr/lib/libgmodule-2.0.so: could not read symbols: File in wrong format`

Comment: How can i solve this?

Comment: I decided to give you the points, even though you don't answer to my comments. But at least you answered the question on how to compile with the cross compiler.

Comment: "even though you don't answer to my comments" — I'm sorry. Your first comment was related to not having installed the toolchain. Your second comment fixes that. Your third comment seems like it's a different problem, maybe specific to whatever software you're trying to build, but cannot be answered without more details about what "not creating the necessary files anymore" means. Your other comments I didn't see until just now, owing to having been busy travelling.

Comment: "File in wrong format" sounds like either (1) you previously built for the native platform and now that file is interfering with the cross build for the other platform. Best to "make clean" after changing platforms. Or (2) the Makefile is incorrectly building some targets for the native platform and others for the cross platform. Even though you specified an alternate compiler maybe a native platform compiler is hardcoded somewhere in the Makefile. For that, you're have to find what needs updating in the Makefile and improve it.

Comment: Thank you for answering my questions, i will double check everything and try again. The necessary files are e.g. sdptool, hcitool, hciconfig etc.. But thats another problem and i won't extend it here. Thank you again for your help!

Answer (score 1):

More than a cross-compiler, what you need is a [toolchain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toolchain), since there are more steps involving the process of getting an executable out of source code. These steps are

1. Compile (source code to assembler)
2. Assemble (assembler code to machine code)
3. Link (routines and libraries in machine code linked together)

The naming standard in GNU toolchains is `<target>-<tool>`, for example `arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-gcc` would be the compiler for an ARM architecture, Open Embedded Linux variant, while `arm-oe-linux-gnueabi-as` is the assembler of the same toolchain, and so on.

However, that is not all that you need to get from source code in the host to executable for the target machine, you need also the headers and libraries from the target machine in your host machine for the linker. That's why you had that build error "could not read symbols. File in wrong format".
Of course, once you have the headers and sysroot and everything copied into your host machine, you need to set the corresponding variables for the cross-compiler to find the right ones, and not the original from your host machine.

Generally speaking, source packages contain a Makefile prepared to accept a specific compiler. Seeing from previous comments, I gathered that you solved that much using the CC= variable. As soon as you have all set, just change the CC for your Makefile and call `make`.

So, long story short, you need to build your own toolchain for your target machine in your host machine or get an already built one.

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I already have a toolchain `arm-linux-gcc-4.4.3.tgz` like i wrote on the first post. I am confused because of `target`and `host`. If i am right, then host is the actual target, on which the application should run, and target is the machine on which i build the application?

Comment: My wording "toolchain" rather than "compiler" was to make a point: you need more than a cross-compiler ;)
Wrong: Host is where you make **all compilation processes**, target is where you **run** the results. BUT the host needs the libraries and headers **of the target** to provide them to the toolchain in order to produce finished, executable binaries for the target.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, some other stack overflow user confused me by writing that host is the system on which the generated program will run. I give you +1 because of your effort

Answer (score 1):

The host is the machine that you are cross compiling on.  Your development machine.
The target is the ARM926EJ-S machine.
A couple of things to watch out for:
ARM926EJ-S is an ARMv5 make sure your cross tool chain compiles for the correct version of arm processor.
The install directory called for in the make file:
INSTALL = /usr/bin/install -c
I think this will install onto your host (development) machine, not what you want.
If you are cross compiling this for a embedded device, you will need to create a 'workingInstall' directory to install bluez into. Then add this to your embedded file system. (nand, sd card).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As you can read on the following website:
`--host: In which system the generated program will run.`
so if this info is correct, then it means, host is the machine on where i compile my applications?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27188116/cross-build-third-party-library-locations-on-linux