# How to find out triplet without gcc?

Tags: cross-compilation

I try to find out the [triplet](http://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet) for my device, because [i try to cross compile](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/225116/how-to-use-my-cross-compiler-to-compile-something), but there is no gcc installed on the target device and i am not allowed to install it.

With gcc installed i could just write `gcc -dumpmachine`

Is it possible to find this information without gcc?

Comment: how far will `uname -a` get you here?

Comment: i get `Linux MyDeviceName 2.6.35.3-571-gcca29a0-g8b63513-dirty #162 PREEMPT Tue Aug 4 10:57:29 CEST 2015 armv5tejl GNU/Linux`

Comment: Can you tell us the manufacturer and model of the target device, for example `Freescale MX28EVK` ?

Comment: No i can't, its a small special device with a metal housing and nothing written on it.

Comment: So you have a `armv5tejl` core, `GNU/Linux` as OS, and if you really need the vendor, too, try `lshw -class cpu` and ignore the "should be run as super-user" part.

Comment: @Fiximan thx for your answer, unfortunattely i get `-sh: lshw: not found`, but i think i can just write `unknown` at the vendor part.

Comment: @Fiximan The precise CPU model isn't relevant here. The exact role of the “vendor” part of the triplet is somewhat variable; here what matters is which ABI (e.g. for ARM there's little-endian vs big-endian, soft vs hard float, ...).

Comment: check also http://askubuntu.com/questions/872457/how-to-determine-the-host-multi-arch-default-folder

Answer (score 14):

You can get a lot of information by means of `uname` and also by checking with `file` the type of executables:

```
$ gcc -dumpmachine
x86_64-linux-gnu
$ uname -o -m
x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ file /usr/bin/file
/usr/bin/file: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=d8ac02806880576708bf189c064fca78ea89f1d0, stripped
```

If your device doesn't have `file` installed, copy a binary executable from it to another Linux computer and run `file` there.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Where can i find a binary executable? Under /usr/bin ? Sorry, im pretty much beginner, so an example would be great.

Comment: If you got the file command as shown in the snippet above you can use it itself as executable example. Otherwise any other file in /usr/bin should do.

Comment: uname -o -m gives `armv7l GNU/Linux` instead of `arm-linux-gnueabihf`

Answer (score 5):

You'll need to find files in the file system which preserve the triplet passed to / probed by `configure` on the build time of your target userland.

In common GNU/Linux distributions the best bet would be querying to common command binaries like `bash` `curl` `make` `svn`.  In the following example on [Debian/armhf](https://wiki.debian.org/ArmHardFloatPort) (QEMU image taken from [here](https://people.debian.org/~aurel32/qemu/armhf/)) I got the *canonical* triplet `arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf` by `bash --version`.  So it would be basically safe to configure my cross toolchain for this system by `/path/to/configure --target=arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf`.

```
root@debian-armhf:~# bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.2.37(1)-release (arm-unknown-linux-gnueabihf)
Copyright (C) 2011 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>

This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

There's no reliable way to know non-canonical triplet like `arm-linux-gnueabihf` `x86_64-linux-gnu` from the userland, and there might be distribution specific conventions like Debian [multiarch](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch) and [tuples](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/Tuples).  You'll need to collect info from your distribution's document or other resources online.

Comment: Thx for your answer, but unfortunattely the command "bash" is not available too.

Comment: Which distribution are you using

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `make -v`. In my laptop:

```
$ make -v 
GNU Make 4.1
Built for x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Copyright (C) 1988-2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Then built triple is `x86_64-pc-linux-gnu`.

Comment: Turns out this answer is wrong. The build triplet is `x86_64-linux-gnu` despite what `make` says.

Comment: @Joshua Please read this: https://wiki.osdev.org/Target_Triplet

Comment: Most people need to know the triplet either to know what to pass to `./configure` or to cross-compile something. When cross-compiling, the only name that is relevant is the name the cross tools will take.